# Updating a mysql text field with new values

Tags: php, mysql

i have a database with start date, end date and text field containing multiple strings, each of them starting with a mysql formatted date within the range of start and end date.

let's say i want to duplicate the record with a new start date and a new end date, i need to update those strings. no problem there. i extract them from the old record and update in the foreach loop with the new date range. except some strings can have the same dates.

```
$data_acc = explode(';', $record['details_accommodation'], -1);

foreach($data_acc as $row_acc) 
{
   list($day,$name,$sgl,$dbl,$tpl,$nights,$status) = explode(',', $row_acc);
}
```

how can i detect within the loop all the same dates (`$day`) and update with the new values without incrementing automatically ?

Comment: in that case each $day will auto increment of one day. but let's say i have two old entries with 2012-01-01 and one with 2012-01-02 and i change the starting date to 2012-05-05, i don't want my new entries to have 2012-05-5, 2012-05-6 and 2012-05-7 but 2012-05-05 for the two first and then then 2012-05-6 for the third one.

Comment: Sorry that makes no sense for me.

Comment: I agree with @rekire, that explanation was a bit dense. Can you add a clearer explanation to the question, maybe with additional code?